# Matplotlib сохранение в pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib

По умолчанию сохраняется видимая область графика, а как сохранить весь график с определенным масштабом, если он длинный?
Допустим хочу сохранить этот график с шагом 1 в pdf[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

ax[0].plot(range(2000), 'r')
ax[1].plot(range(2000), 'g')
ax[1].tick_params(labelleft='off',left=False)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

plt.show()

fig.savefig("foo.pdf")
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно как должен выглядеть PDF? Что не устраивает в текущем варианте?

Comment: Хочу чтобы в pdf было длинный график с шагом допустим